# lessen the gap between float:left and float:right

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin, padding

I have `.content-left` and `.content-right`, which are intended to be floated left and right, respectively. My problem is that the two divs are both set to `width:300px`, which is considerably less than the width of the container(960px). I think this is what's causing such a large gap between `.content-left` and `.content-right`. My question is- how do I lessen the gap? Negative padding and margins don't seem to work in this case.

CSS:

```
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}

.content-left {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}

.content-right {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <h1>Heading.</h1>
    <div class="content-left">
        //left side content
    </div><!-- end content-left -->
    <div class="content-right">
        //right side content
    </div><!-- end content-right -->
</div><!-- end container -->
```

[image: gap]

Comment: Umm, 300+300 = 600. 960-600 = 360 - of course there's a significant gap?

You can try increasing the width of each one (maybe use a %, such as 45%?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try floating both to the left. Then use some `margin`

If you really want to use float left and float right, adding `margin-right` to the one floated right will work.

Answer (score 0):

Margins does not work? Hmm, no, it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/NF8Lk/